# Anything faster than a UIButton?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uibutton, touchscreen

I'm writing an iPhone app which needs an extremely rapid response for a touch event. Is there any object that will provide a faster response than the UIControlEventTouchDown result of a UIButton loaded from a nib? I'm open to any resources that don't require extensive digging around or reverse engineering.

Thanks in advance!

Luke

Comment: Do you know that a UIButton isn't fast enough? You're probably not going to be dealing with touches faster than 4 a second, so you'll have a whole 250ms in between each tap to get ready for the next one...

Comment: Very true. The thing is they have to be in precise rhythm. So even with pretty widely spaced touches, a delay of even 20 ms or so is problematic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably not.  Though you could create your own subclass of `UIView` which implements `- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event` (and other similar methods).  Though it's likely that this is exactly what UIButton does for you anyway.

If a `UIButton` isn't fast enough, try a subclass.  But I don't think it will be much different.